# how to connect ubuntu 18.04 to wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-mate

I am trying to connect my computer with Ubuntu 18.04 to a wifi network using the option `System/Control Center/Internet and Network/Network Connections`, but I only see a dialog with networks already set, and when I push `add`, I don't know how to tell Ubuntu to detect available networks.

[image]

I believe my wifi might be disabled, but I don't know where to find it. I checked [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html.en), but I don't have the `wifi not connected` option in my system menu.

I checked for the wifi adapter with `lshw -C network`, and this is what I got:

[image]

Sorry if the question is too silly, I am not an Ubuntu expert user.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: You can't view the available networks? or you can view it and you just can't connect?

Comment: @user535733 done.

Comment: @Fortem I added an image of what I can see.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -r wl && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe brcmsmac` does wifi work then?

Comment: @Jeremy31 actually, the opposite, now Ubuntu can't recognize the wifi card. It could before

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`